# SSH option not visible under Bamboo shared credentials option

Tags: bamboo, bamboo-specs

Under Bamboo (Datacenter) shared credentials option, only the "AWS" option is visible. How do we enable SSH under the shared credentials option?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Bamboo plugin with SSH and Username/password shared credentials failed. Please try to restart instance and report to support.atlassian.com if issue is not resolved